# Insert cell in link

Tags: excel, hyperlink, reference, excel-formula, vlookup

Is there any way to replace a file name for a cell reference. I have the below VLOOKUP

```
=VLOOKUP(A10,'R:\HDV Brand\Weekly Forecast\Forecast 2017-18\[HDVSTA.xlsm]RAW DATA'!$A:$AB,26,)
```

and I want to replace HDVSTA for the text that it is in cell D10 so I can drag down the formula and complete the rest of the rows with the reference in column D.......

Any advice how to do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use INDIRECT().

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this would work but try:

***Edit, as per Scotts comment***

```
=VLOOKUP(A10,INDIRECT("'R:\HDV Brand\Weekly Forecast\Forecast 2017-18[" & D1 & ".xlsm]RAW DATA'!$A:$AB"),26)
```

Comment: my bad, you should just post as answer dude, your clearly an excel ninja

Comment: Naw, don't care about the points as much as teaching the proper methods.

Comment: @ScottCraner that's cool man, hope one day I can pass on the stuff I've learnt from sites like this

Comment: Thank you guys but it returns #REF! Cell A10 is a concatenate linked to the spreadsheet that is in each file.

Comment: @Diego i think its the placment of quatation marks, try =VLOOKUP(A10,INDIRECT("R:\HDV Brand\Weekly Forecast\Forecast 2017-18\[" & D1 & ".xlsm]RAW DATA'!$A:$AB"),26) this works for me on a tester sheet

Comment: Is it possible that ref_text is not a valid? This is a file outside the spreadsheet, not a text string.

Comment: @Diego it may be that you need the other workbook open possibly

Comment: The external spreadsheet has to be opened for `INDIRECT` to work. You will need to try Google `INDIRECT.EXT` or Harlan Grove's `PULL` function.